# INNER JOIN está duplicando registro

Tags: php, sql, join

Tenho um INNER JOIN que está duplicando registros na exibição. Pois no banco de dados tais registros não estão duplicados.

```
select 
 conta.dominio,
 conta.id,
 conta.modelo,
 imoveis.id,
 imoveis.cod,
 imoveis.titulo,
 imoveis.vvenda,
 imoveis.vtemporada,
 imoveis.vanual,
 imoveis.tipo,
 fotos.cod,
 fotos.foto,
 imoveis.descricao,
 imoveis.cidade, 
 imoveis.data, 
 imoveis.endereco, 
 conta.nome, 
 imoveis.dormitorio, 
 imoveis.banheiro, 
 imoveis.atotal, 
 imoveis.areatotalmedida 

  from 
   conta 

   inner join imoveis on 
    conta.id = imoveis.cod 

   inner join fotos on 
    fotos.cod = imoveis.id;
```

Como solucionar esta questão? O porque isso está acontecendo?

Agradeço.

Comment: Me mostra quais são as chaves das tabelas, coloca a definição de cada uma ai.

Comment: Imagino que se existam N fotos por imovel, logo vai repetir as informações dele para foto, pode explicar melhor o contexto do código?

Comment: faz um teste ! coloca select * from 
   conta 

   inner join imoveis on 
    conta.id = imoveis.cod 

   inner join fotos on 
    fotos.cod = imoveis.id;
e verifica se existem realmente linhas duplicadas ( todos os campos retornados devem ser identicos , tem que ter algo diferente se não um select distinct funcionaria )

Answer (score 3):

Analisando a estrutura acredito que seja da seguinte forma

(conta) 1 - N (imoveis) 1 - N (fotos)

Onde temos uma conta com vários imóveis, e um imóvel tem várias fotos.
Com Inner Join em nenhum momento poderá repetir os registros, o que pode estar acontecendo é que para cada registro da tabela foto está trazendo os registros da tabela imóveis, é o que deve acontecer pois para cada registro de "Foto" existe um de "Imovel".

Answer (score 0):

Se seus dados realmente estão duplicados nas tabelas você pode usa o `distinct`,

```
select distinct conta.dominio,conta.id,conta.modelo,imoveis.id,imoveis.cod,imoveis.titulo,imoveis.vvenda,imoveis.vtemporada,imoveis.vanual,imoveis.tipo,fotos.cod,fotos.foto,imoveis.descricao,imoveis.cidade, imoveis.data, imoveis.endereco, conta.nome, imoveis.dormitorio, imoveis.banheiro, imoveis.atotal, imoveis.areatotalmedida from conta inner join imoveis on conta.id = imoveis.cod inner join fotos on fotos.cod=imoveis.id
```

Comment: O distinct não resolveu

Comment: São todas as colunas que estão duplicadas ? e qual o banco de dados?

Comment: Quem voltou contra tem alguma justificativa?

Comment: @gladison-neuza-perosini é bem provável que os dados não estejam duplicados, pois o distinct do nosso amigo marconcilio-souza resolveria o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Eu já tive esse problema, e utilizei o desmembramento das queries para entender seu resultado não satisfatório ao que eu desejava.
Oriento você efetuar o seguinte:

Possível problema que você está tendo:

1. possue uma Conta para vários imóveis
2. possue um imóvel para várias fotos

   select
   c.id,c.dominio,c.modelo,
   i.cod,i.id,i.titulo,i.vvenda,i.vtemporada,i.vanual,
   i.tipo,i.descricao,i.cidade,i.data,i.endereco,
   i.dormitorio,i.banheiro,i.atotal,i.areatotalmedida 
   from conta c 
   inner join imoveis i on c.id=i.cod
3. Verifique se ocorre duplicação de dados

   a) faça um select sem o Distinct

   b) abra outra janela no seu banco de dados e faça com o Distinct e analise se tem duplicidade

2) Ocorrendo duplicidade
    a) exportar para o excel e filtre somente os duplicados o restante delete...assim você irá visualizar por que contem mais de um resultado para o mesmo ID/COD

3) Faça o mesmo com a tabela fotos e imoveis
    a) creio que exista mais de uma foto para mesmo imóvel, desta forma ocorre a duplicidade

Possível solução para a tabela fotos e imoveis:

1) fazer uma consulta para contas e imóveis, depois recuperar os ids e fazer um segundo select para resgatar todas as fotos dos imóveis

espero ter lhe dado um norte.

Comment: Por favor, informar uma ideia melhor quem deu negativo

Comment: Só um brainstorm, tá? Provavelmente: 1) porque é uma pergunta extremamente vaga e sem detalhes necessários para apresentar uma resposta adequada; 2) porque sua formatação está um pouco confusa; 3) porque você apontou o norte e a pessoa estava procurando o sul.

Comment: Caro @brasofilo por favor ajude a solucionarmos este problema com sua ilustre resposta, pois pelo que percebi não consta nenhuma resposta tua ou tentativa de ajudar ao companheiro gladison

Comment: **Eu não negativei sua resposta**. Estou tentando explicar os possíveis motivos desses votos. Obviamente, tentar ajudar pode ser confundido com ofensa... desculpa aê, vou evitar esse tipo de coisa de agora em diante